# There are no Import javafx.scene.media.mediaplayer

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to build player music in java by netbaens 
I have netbans 7.4
Jdk 1.7
Want i import javafx.scene.media.mediaplayer
But this object not find in my version java 
Can I add this example download it and installed in my java or I must download the last version of netbeans and jdk

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. And why the diacritics?

Comment: Can you explain me